# Filtering columns in Cassandra

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, cassandra, pycassa

I am new to Cassandra.

Lets say I have 1,000,000 columns. I would like to return only columns that have the string 'test' in the column name.

Is it possible with Cassandra/Pycassa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only filter columns whose names start with "test". Otherwise you'll have to do the filtering in your own code.

Comment: Can you please give us a small example on how to filter the column name from the code?

Comment: use column_family.get('a_row_key') to get a list of all columns for the given row key then iterate on that dictionary to test each entry to see whether or not the column name in that entry contains the substring 'test'